# delegate methods not passing data over to second view controller

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, delegates, protocols, viewcontroller

Hi my delegate isn't passing an image and some strings to my second navigation controller. Can anyone see whats wrong? I've created ImageAndTextDelegate.h , PhotoEditViewController.h/.m and PreviewFrameViewController.h/.m . Basically after selecting some images and typing some text in photoedit. i wanna send the data through to previewframe using my delegate methods.

```
//ImageAndTextDelegate.h
@protocol ImageAndTextDelegate

-(void)passImage:(UIImage*)image;
-(void)passMainText:(NSString*)maintext withSubText:(NSString*)subtext;

@end
```

> //PhotoEditViewController.h
>       #import "ImageAndTextDelegate.h"
>
> ```
> @interface PhotoEditViewController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate,
> ```
>
> UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>{
>           IBOutlet UITextField *mainText;
>           IBOutlet UITextField *subText;
>           IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
>           IBOutlet UIButton *previewPictureButton;
>       }
>
> ```
> @property (nonatomic,retain) UITextField *mainText;
> @property (nonatomic,retain) UITextField *subText;
> @property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageView;
> @property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *previewPictureButton;
> @property (nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet id<ImageAndTextDelegate> delegate;
>
> -(IBAction)previewPicture:(id)sender;
>
> @end
> ```

```
//PhotoEditViewController.m
         #import "PhotoEditViewController.h"
         #import "PreviewFrameViewController.h"

         @implementation PhotoEditViewController
         @synthesize delegate;
         -(IBAction)previewPicture:(id)sender{
             PreviewFrameViewController* prvc = [[PreviewFrameViewController alloc]init];
             [delegate passImage:imageView.image];
             [delegate passMainText:mainText.text withSubText:subText.text];
             [self.navigationController pushViewController:prvc animated:YES];
         }
         - (void)viewDidLoad
         {
             [super viewDidLoad];
             // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib. 
         }
```

> ```
> //PreviewFrameViewController.h
> #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
> #import "ImageAndTextDelegate.h"
>
> @interface PreviewFrameViewController : UIViewController<ImageAndTextDelegate>{
>     IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;
>     IBOutlet UILabel *main;
>     IBOutlet UILabel *sub;
> }
>
> @property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *myImage;
> @property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *main;
> @property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *sub;
>
> @end
> ```

```
//PreviewFrameViewController.m
#import "PreviewFrameViewController.h"
#import "PhotoEditViewController.h"

@implementation PreviewFrameViewController

@synthesize myImage,main,sub;

-(void)passImage:(UIImage *)image{
    myImage.image = image;
}

-(void)passMainText:(NSString *)maintext withSubText:(NSString *)subtext{
    main.text = maintext;
    sub.text = subtext;
}
-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PhotoEditViewController* pvc = [[PhotoEditViewController alloc]init];
    pvc.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your PhotoEditViewController is creating and presenting a PreviewFrameViewController.

Then in its viewDidLoad, your PreviewFrameViewController is creating **its own** PhotoEditViewController and setting that instance's delegate to itself.

So you've got **two** PhotoEditViewControllers now, and the first one still has no delegate. (Which leads to the question of why you needed the delegate pattern here to begin with?)

The most direct way to do what you seem to want is this (in your PhotoEditViewController):

```
-(IBAction)previewPicture:(id)sender{

    PreviewFrameViewController* prvc = [[PreviewFrameViewController alloc]init];
    [prvc passImage:imageView.image];
    [prvc passMainText:mainText.text withSubText:subText.text];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:prvc animated:YES];

    // You could have set self.delegate here, but I'm not sure why you need that now
    // but if for some reason you do: self.delegate = prvc;

    // and if you aren't using ARC: [prvc release];

}
```

I hope that makes sense?